# PHP SQL query returns 'unknown colum' when string data type

Tags: php, joomla

I'm having a problem querying a database. I have been provided the environment so I can not change. And it's a Joomla that I'm trying to adapt to be able to work with a database.

I created the query and I get the data to be inserted correctly when they are numbers, but if I enter a string it returns 'unknown column'.

It is probably a problem with single or double quoting and how the PHP code is being interpreted but I can not see it and I come to see if anyone could lend a hand.

Here is the PHP code I am adding. Supported by JDatabase expressions that joomla provide.

```
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Insert columns.
$columns = array("De", "Para");

// Insert values.
$data = $_POST['form'];
$de = $data[De];
$para = $data[Para];

$values = array($de, $para);

// Prepare the insert query.
$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('referencias'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
 // ->values($de, $para);

  ->values(implode(',', $values));

// Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

Im trying with 2 fields (columns) of the form as you see. If I type 'asfasd' in one of the fields and POST the form it returns:

> Unknown column 'asfasd' in 'field list'

But if I type a number it just add the register to database.

Edit: Data type is 'varchar' in SQL Database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Column in db is set as a number?

Comment: @Syfer it is set as varchar

Answer (score 1):

```
$values = array($de, $para);
```

Let's assume that `De = 3` and `Para = asd`

```
$values_str = implode(',', $values);
```

`$values_str` will be `3','asd`

```
$values_str = "'" . $values_str . "'"; \\<--This is missing step
```

Now, `$values_str` will be `'3','asd'`

```
.
.
.
->values($values_str);
```

I don't know why you want to make a string by imploding the values. But, if you want to, you have to append the quotes on both ends.

Comment: Oh sorry, I had it without ' but I ve forget to change it for publishing here when I was doing some attempts.
Exactly I had 
$de =  $data[De];
$para = $data[Para];

Trying what you purpose right now. And returns same error . Thank u very much.

Comment: Can you please provide datatype of the columns `De` and `Para`? I guess, if the field's datatype is number, you should not wrap it in single quote which is what you are doing at the moment via implode in your code.

Comment: it is declared as varchar in SQL database. I add the info to the post. thank u.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer. It helps to understand how it is being with quotes and double quotes.. From that Im gonna modify the code and see if I can do it without using implode as you suggest. (I must say I copied that part of code and now that you say it has not much sense to use it there) Thank you very much, you helped me to know why it was really failing. it is already not working with exactly your code but it will.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback and I am glad that my answer has helped you fixing your issue.